# Given a MCIR routing number, how does one find the "fractional routing number"?

Tags: united-states, check

I'm trying to order checks for the first time, and the check provider is asking for me to provide a routing number and checking account number, both provided by my bank. However, they're also asking for the "fractional form" of the routing number, which is not provided by my bank, and which I can't look up on a check. (This is my first time ordering checks from this bank)

Is there some way to generate the fractional number given the MCIR routing number?

(Even [Bank of America's Own Site](http://www.bankofamerica.com/deposits/checksave/index.cfm?template=lc_faq_direct) lists the routing number 051000017, but the fractional number is the placeholder 123456789)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The fractional number goes like this: XX-YYYY/ZZZZ.

ZZZZ is the first 4 digits of your routing number (you can skip the leading zeroes).

YYYY is the next 4 digits of your routing number (the last, 9th digit, is control digit).

XX is the city/state where the bank is located (I believe its based on the original HQ, I know that for WF in California its 11, which is San Francisco). You can find the full list on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Routing_transit_number), once the blackout is over (in the mean time - call your Congressman and voice your objections to [SOPA](https://www.google.com/landing/takeaction/)).

Best would be to get an existing check, and copy from it.

You can also use [this site](http://www.routingnumbers.org/), which will give you the bank address given the routing number, and based on the address you can deduce the value for XX. For 051000017 it should be 68, for Virginia. So on your checks should appear "68-1/510"

By the way - I deposited checks without the fractional routing number, and they were cashed perfectly fine. I don't think its required any longer, and for automatic processing you only need the MCIR.